# CustomMultipartstreamprovider threw and exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using asp.net mvc 4 for service. I need to be able to accept POSTED images/files from client applications. i wrote a code it was working fine but now after 2 to 3 weeks its not working show an exception

> CustomMultipartstreamprovider  threw an exception

don't know what is the problem kindly need some help.

my code is

```
public class UploadController : ApiController
    {
        private static IExceptionLogs _iException = new ExceptionLogsBLO();
        private readonly static string className = "Upload";
        private static string methodName = string.Empty;

        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFile() 
        {
            methodName = "PostFile";

            // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }

            //string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
            string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files");

            var provider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
            //var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).ContinueWith();

            try
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // Holds the response body
                string senderID = null;
                string receiverId = null;
                string Exten = null;
                Int64 Type = 0;
                Int64 IsGroup = 0;
                // Read the form data and return an async task.
                await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

                // This illustrates how to get the form data.
                foreach (var key in provider.FormData.AllKeys)
                {
                   // Trace.WriteLine(key.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);


                    foreach (var val in provider.FormData.GetValues(key))
                    {
                        sb.Append(string.Format("{0}: {1}\n", key, val));
                        if (key == "senderId") 
                        {
                            senderID = val;
                        }
                        else if(key == "receiverId")
                        {
                             receiverId = val;
                        }
                        else if(key == "exten")
                        {
                            Exten = val;
                        }
                        else if (key == "fileType") 
                        {
                            if (val == "image")
                            {
                                Type = 1;
                            }
                            else if (val == "audio")
                            {
                                Type = 2;
                            }
                            else if (val == "video")
                            {
                                Type = 4;
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                Type = 3;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (key == "IsGroup")
                        {

                            IsGroup = Convert.ToInt64(val);
                        }

                    }
                }

                // This illustrates how to get the file names for uploaded files.
                foreach (var file in provider.FileData)
                {
                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file.LocalFileName);
                    sb.Append(string.Format("Uploaded file: {0} ({1} bytes)\n", fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.Length));

                    // file save in database code 
                    FileUploadModel fileData = new FileUploadModel();

                    fileData.FileName = fileInfo.Name;
                    fileData.FileType = Type;
                    fileData.SenderId = Convert.ToInt64(senderID);
                   // fileData.ReceiverId = Convert.ToInt64(receiverId);
                    fileData.ReceiverId = receiverId;
                    fileData.FileExten = Exten;
                    fileData.IsRead = Convert.ToBoolean(0);
                    fileData.date = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
                    fileData.IsGroup = IsGroup;

                    FileUploadBLO fileBlo = new FileUploadBLO();

                    DbResult result = fileBlo.FileUploadData(fileData);

                }
                return new HttpResponseMessage()
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(sb.ToString())
                };
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionLogsModel error = new ExceptionLogsModel(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace.ToString(), DateTime.Now, className, methodName);
                _iException.InsertException(error);

            }

            return null;

        }

    }



 class CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider : MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
    {
        public CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(string path)
            : base(path)
        { }

        public override string GetLocalFileName(HttpContentHeaders headers)
        {
            return headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
           // var name = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(headers.ContentDisposition.FileName) ? headers.ContentDisposition.FileName : "NoName";
           // return name.Replace("\"", string.Empty); //this is here because Chrome submits files in quotation marks which get treated as part of the filename and get escaped
        }
    }
```

Comment: and what's the exception ?

Comment: The stream provider of type 'CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider' threw an exception.

this is the exception @Dhavl Patel

Comment: what you have got in path ?

Comment: sorry??? what do you mean by path??

Comment: CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider class string path I am talkin about that path

Comment: string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files"); this defines the path its a separate folder in the same folder where the code is place, i think its a problem of read write ,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54489/discussion-between-dhaval-patel-and-user3359326).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, The file upload target folder (in which file saved) was different from the Virtual directory of Web Application directory chain, this exception occurred. As an obvious solution, keep file target folder as part of web application directory, worker process will have proper access to save  the file. 
The nasty part is exception does not say about it :( like 'access denied'... weird exception.

Hope it helps,